# How do you make a PDF searchable with text in the sidebar?

Tags: python, pdf

I'm looking to create some PDF's from Python.

I've noticed that some pdf's have sidebar text that allows you to see the context of occurrences of search terms.

e.g. search for "dictionary"

View in Sidebar:

Page 10 Assigning a value to an existing **dictionary** key simply replaces the old value with a new one.

How is that done?

Is there anyway to convert existing PDFs to render this sidebar text?

Comment: Is that not a feature of the PDF reader software?

Comment: The sidebar search text is a feature of PDF reader software, but I've notices some documents show the searches in context of the page and some don't. I was trying to determine why.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Reportlab](http://www.reportlab.org/) to generate your pdfs, then there are facilities in the library to bookmark as you want. Checkout the `bookmarkPage` method on page 54 of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're referring to are bookmarks. The [first hit on Google](http://www.ehow.com/how_10082_create-bookmarks-pdf.html) indicates that you can put them in by hand with Acrobat Pro.

The [DocBook XSL](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/) templates when used with [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)

Answer (score 0):

The [PyQt gui toolkit](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com) has support for creating PDF's. See for example: [Printing Rich Text with Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/richtext-common-tasks.html)